# Nginx is not working with docker-compose for react app

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have created nginx config, DockerFile, Docker-compose file for the same.

> nginx/nginx.conf

```
 server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

> DockerFile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
```

Now after  doing `docker-compose up --build`

I get the logs as

```
client    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
client    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
client    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
client    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
client    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packages version
client    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
client    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

I am not sure, if the problem is due to different packages version or something else but when tried to visit the url it says this site can’t be reached.

Comment: do you get additional logs after you visit url? Also what output gives ```docker ps```

Comment: No.. I think browser not reaching to the server

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which url you are using, but it looks like your nginx is exposed on port 80. You need to expose that port in docker compose. Include under the ports:

```
- 80:80
```

Comment: I have added this -80:80 under port in docker-compose, still not working

Comment: run "docker ps" and check if your container is running and what ports are exposed.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue and any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Dockerfile

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

should be

```
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

> nginx.conf

```
    listen 80;
```

should be

```
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
```